# Including global libraries requiring other global libraries in a jspm/systemjs setup

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js, systemjs, jspm

I'm looking for a solution to include a global library: in this case [jquery-mentions-input](https://podio.github.io/jquery-mentions-input/) in an es6/jspm project.

It does not have an npm package so can only be included via the `github:` registry.

(The question would equally apply to those packages that also don't have such files - so please don't say something like "fork it")

This package for instance requires underscore and jquery (it expects both as globals and adds `$.fn.mentionsInput` to the existing global `jQuery`.

How would I include it?

I'm trying this in package.json:

```
"overrides": {
    "github:podio/jquery-mentions-input@1.6.0": {
        "format": "global",
        "registry": "github",
        "shim": {
            "jquery-mentions-input": {
                "deps": [
                    "jquery",
                    "underscore"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

or this in config.js:

```
"jquery-mentions-input": {
    "format": "global",
    "deps": [
        "jquery",
        "underscore"
    ],
    "exports": "$.mentionsInput"
}
```

but unfortunately, even using this:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import _ from 'underscore';
import 'jquery-mentions-input';
```

just reports a `_ is not defined` error.

I've even tried hacking:

```
import _ from 'underscore';
window._ = global._ = _;
```

but to no avail.

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Cheers